# Como separar as folhas de estilo usando Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, wpf, xamarin-forms, xaml

Olá, estou vindo do WPF onde é possível criar meus arquivos de estilo em arquivos separados e a partir dos mesmos utilizar nos meu `UserControl`'s as mesmas configurações de estilo. Fiz algumas (muitas) pesquisas e encontrei algumas referencias como essa:

[https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/)

Mas infelizmente não consegui entender como separar minhas folhas de estilo de forma "coerente" assim como estou acostumado a fazer no WPF ou na web.

Hoje a estrutura comum que utilizo em meus projetos WPF fica assim:

```
App
|- App.xaml.cs
|- Assets
   |- Fonts
   |- Styles
      |- Colors.xaml
      |- Fonts.xaml
      ...
   |- Images
```

E em meu arquivo root (App.xaml) eu faço a importação dos dicionários de estilos, assim:

```
<Application 
    x:Class="Teste.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Teste"
    StartupUri="Views/Dialogs/SplashDialog.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/Styles/Fonts.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/Styles/Badges.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/Styles/Buttons.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/Styles/Tabs.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/Styles/Aligns.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="./Assets/Styles/Forms.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Como faço para aplicar a mesma "lógica" estrutural à uma aplicação Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Verificou se o path está certo? tentou só `<ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml"/>`

Comment: Sim vi, tenho essa pasta `Assets/Styles/` no meu diretório root do projeto principal do Xamarin